# How to create a VM running Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 5 without Desktop Experience on Azure?

Tags: azure, windows-server-core, windows-server-2016

The default installation of Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 5 at Azure installs it with the Desktop Experience. The graphical interface is not needed for running my application there though. So the question is how to create a VM running Windows Server 2016 so that the graphical interface would not be there, so basically a "Core" edition?

Answer based on ARM template would be nice if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no option to run a Core installation on Azure.

For previous versions this meant that you had to uninstall the GUI features after configuring your VM.
However, server 2016 [unfortunately removed this feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/get-started/installation-options-for-windows-server-2016-technical-preview).

So for server 2016, it looks like you're stuck with the GUI version.
You can always open a [feedback ticket](https://feedback.azure.com/) to azure. And request the addition of a core version.
However this was done for the 2012 version and it did not garner enough attention to be considered.

Comment: There actually was a core gallery image for TP4, wonder why it was removed in TP5.